# How to Properly Exit Airflow Standalone?

Tags: python, airflow, local

I am running `airflow standalone` as a local development environment. I followed the [instructions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) provided by Airflow to setup the environment, but now I'd like to shut it down in the most graceful way possible.

I ran the standalone command in a terminal, and so my first attempt was to simply use `Ctrl+C`. It looks promising:

```
triggerer | [2022-02-02 10:44:06,771] {triggerer_job.py:251} INFO - 0 triggers currently running
^Cstandalone | Shutting down components
```

However, even 10 minutes later, the shutdown is still in progress, with no more messages in the terminal. I used `Ctrl+C` again and got a `KeyboardInterrupt`. Did I do this the wrong way? Is there a better way to shut down the standalone environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (in bash):

`pkill --signal 2 -u $USER airflow`

or

`pkill --signal 15 -u $USER airflow`

or

`pkill --signal 9 -u $USER airflow`

Say what?

Here's more description of each part:

- `pkill` - Process kill function.
- `--signal` - Tells what 'signal' to send to the process
- `2 | 15 | 9` - Is the id for the terminal signal to send.

  - `2` = SIGINT, which is like `CTRL + C`.
  - `15` = SIGTERM, the default for `pkill`.
  - `9` = SIGKILL, which doesn't messaround with gracefully ending a process.
  - For more info, run `kill -L` in your bash terminal.
- `-u` - Tells the functon to only match processes whose real user ID is listed.
- `$USER` - The current session user environment variable.  This may be different on your system, so adjust accordingly.
- `airflow` - The name of the selection criteria or pattern to match.

[prep info page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/procps/pgrep.1.en.html) for more detail on the options available.

Comment: I never solved this and I've moved on, but I've marked this as the answer because of the detail. Seems that it would work!